# How to overcome AWS V1 + V2 mismatch while using Java SQS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have the following code with the following maven import:

From pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqs</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.23</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code: (Note this is AWS V2)

```
    SqsClient sqs = SqsClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .build();
```

The rest of my AWS code and imports are using V1. There are no issues when I run this code locally but when I execute it through Lambda --> step function, I get the following exception:

**Error
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException
Cause
{
"errorMessage": "Unable to instantiate executor interceptor for client.",
"errorType": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException",
"stackTrace": [
"software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:98)",
"software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory.createExecutionInterceptor(ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory.java:140)",
"software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory.createExecutionInterceptorFromResource(ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory.java:95)",
"java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:269)",
"java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)",
"java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)",
"java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)",
"java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)",
"java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)...
],
"cause": {
"errorMessage": "software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.internal.MessageMD5ChecksumInterceptor. Current classpath: file:/var/task/",
"errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException",
"stackTrace": []
}
}**

I am using maven shaded plugin in order to reduce my JAR size, however, when I run this code locally it works without any issues. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1491

Comment: How are you running it locally? Are you running with `java -jar` or something else? Do you have _anything_ that would add other V2 JARs onto the classpath? What is the output when you run `mvn dependency:tree`? Is there anything else in the error message that indicates _what_ class is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Susan Mustafa for directing me to the solution and @Parsifal
for you assistant.

As Susan links suggested, I resolved the issue by adding a filter to my maven shade plugin as such:

```
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>software.amazon.awssdk:sqs</artifact>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </filter>
```